# Printing and array two times in python

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have a list `a=['abc','cdv','fasdf']` and also have a constant `n` which says the amount of time print each elements two times.

For example, `n=2` should return `a=['abc','abc','cdv','cdv']`; or `n=4` will return `a=['abc','abc','cdv','cdv','fasdf','fasdf','abc','abc']`.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding what you are asking.  How are `2` and `4` related in your output?

Comment: the constant n is the number of elements which should be printed two times if it is bigger the amount of elements it should start again with first elements

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? You could probably use `itertools` to great effect...

Comment: Okay -- what have you tried?  This seems to incorporate elements you should have had already in your course materials, and are readily available in on-line tutorials.  Where are you stuck, specifically, that you have *no* code?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way using `itertools.chain` and a generator comprehension:

```
from itertools import chain

a = ['abc','cdv','fasdf']
n = 4

res = list(chain.from_iterable([a[i % len(a)]]*2 for i in range(n)))

# ['abc', 'abc', 'cdv', 'cdv', 'fasdf', 'fasdf', 'abc', 'abc']
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you'll need to recycle elements if n is larger than the length of the list. An easy way to deal with this is to duplicated the array as many times as needed.

```
import math
n_over = math.ceil(len(a)/n)
n_reps = 1 + n_over
a_long = a * n_reps
```

we can iterate over the new array to build the new one

```
a_rep = []
for e in a_long[0:n]:
    a_new += [e]*n
```